# USB flash drive won't work at all

Tags: windows-8.1, usb, memory

I plugged in a USB flash drive into my computer. (I got it for free, I don't remember why.) It was 1GB and it didn’t have a brand on it. I’m using Windows 8.1, i5 CPU, 1TB HDD, 12GB RAM

At first it worked fine, then I tried to put “[Kubrick](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=206064)” on it. Then I decided that I didn’t need Kubrick any more so I plugged it in to try to delete Kubrick. Now, it shows up in file explorer but it just says this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to reformat it?

Comment: "A USB" eh?  That's not too helpful. :/  Do other similar devices work OK in your computer?  Did you try the problematic device with another computer?

Comment: I assume when you say "a usb" that you mean a usb drive?

Comment: But other devices work fine and the usb doesn't work on other computers. Right now I have two devices plugged in, a SanDisk and the other free usb, the SanDisk works fine.

Comment: Yep, a usb drive

Comment: @John Have you tried my first suggestion?

Comment: I have tried to: reformat, command prompts "chkdsk" command, and CCleaner's wipe drive feature.

Comment: @John So the formatting tool saw the drive and succeeded in formatting? What file type did you format it as?

Comment: Try changing the filetype to NTFS

Comment: Same result, it didn't work. :(

Comment: If it won't reformat, bin it. They're not worth fighting once they start to fail. Think of it this way - it was worth every penny you paid for it ;)

Answer (score -1):

If original capacity is changed you would have to 0 MBR to restore the original size I believe. I've had a flash drive I formatted for other uses and it reduced from original size to something else tiny. (From gigabytes range to megabytes range.)